# Camera2 API with TextureView/ AutoFitTextureView preview gets stretched in Portrait Mode

Tags: android-camera2, android-textureview

Followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44324039/1427037 
https://inducesmile.com/android/android-camera2-api-example-tutorial/
but still camera2 API gives stretched Preview in Samsung device android 9.0 OS.
Lots of stackoverflow solution already tried but no advantage.
Any help ? 
**Note:** Cant use camera API with SurfaceHolder.

Comment: retested app in Android OS 6.0.1 its working fine. its only stretching in android 9 OS Any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

**check this one**

```
  @Override
  public void setVideoURI(Uri uri) {
    super.setVideoURI(uri);
    MediaMetadataRetriever retr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retr.setDataSource(uri.getPath());
    String height = retr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
    String width = retr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
    try {
      videoRealH = Integer.parseInt(height);
      videoRealW = Integer.parseInt(width);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = getDefaultSize(0, widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = getDefaultSize(0, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (height > width) {

      if (videoRealH > videoRealW) {

        mVideoHeight = height;
        mVideoWidth = width;
      } else {
        mVideoWidth = width;
        float r = videoRealH / (float) videoRealW;
        mVideoHeight = (int) (mVideoWidth * r);
      }
    } else {
      if (videoRealH > videoRealW) {
        mVideoHeight = height;
        float r = videoRealW / (float) videoRealH;
        mVideoWidth = (int) (mVideoHeight * r);
      } else {
        mVideoHeight = height;
        mVideoWidth = width;
      }
    }
    if (videoRealH == videoRealW && videoRealH == 1) {
      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    } else {
      setMeasuredDimension(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
    }

  }
```